# JSF2 with jdbctemplate in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring

I am using JSF2 with Spring3 JDBC template. I have added the following content to the `web.xml` file

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I have added the following code into `faces-config.xml`

```
<application>
<el-resolver>
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
</application>
```

DAO code is the following

```
@Repository
public class XXXDAOImpl implements ZZZDAO{
 @Autowired
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate
 ------------------
}
public void methodname(object){
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlquery,arguments);
}
```

I have added the following code in application context xml file.
    
    
    
    
     
     
     
     
    
    
    
    
    
The managed bean is

```
@ManagedBean(name = "aaaBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerBean{
-----
}
```

I am using Spring 3.0 jar files and javax.faces-2.2.8 jar file.

The intention is to get customer details from a JSF view page and store it in a table.
Upon execution of the code a null pointer exception is thrown from DAO where jdbc template's update method is invoked. Help is apprciated.

Comment: code from application content xml is <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zzz.dao"/>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
 <property name="username" value="case"></property>
 <property name="password" value="case"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />
</bean>